# PHP While Loop wont display data more than once

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm trying to get a while loop to display data in `<span>` field with the a id, each time it loops. But it only display the data on the first loop. What I'm I doing Wrong?

```
<? php

$i = 0;
while($i < 5){
$i++;
echo "<input type = 'hidden' id = 'minute' value = ''>
<input type = 'hidden' id = 'second' value = ''>
<br><br>
<span id = 'selectmin' value = '0'></span>:<span id = 'selectsec' value = 
'0'></span>
<br><br>";
echo "<script>document.getElementById('selectmin').innerHTML = 'Hello ';
</script>";
?>
```

Comment: There's no closing `}` on your `while` loop.

Comment: @AluanHaddad `document.getElementById('selectmin').innerHTML = 'Hello ';`

Comment: @AluanHaddad `<?Javascript echo '<script>alert(phpinfo());</script>'; ?> //confused`

Comment: Wow O_O. I'm confused. `phpinfo` would need to be a global JavaScript variable to be used there

Comment: @YazanWYusuf Can you be more clear on your edit descriptions? 'briefly edit' doesn't tell why you edited the post, nor what the poster should do to fix it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

## This piece of code is not valid in php.

Either use short tags like `<?` or just use qualified PHP tags to avoid such mistakes. There is no space between `<?` and `php`.

Comment: If it worked for u please accept it by ticking it as helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`id='selectmin'` you are creating 5 identical HTML block with the same id? ID are unique and only gonna select the first match that's why it only show once.

Use `'selectmin$i'` so it create a unique id for each loop:

```
<?php

$i = 0;
while($i < 5){
$i++;
echo "<input type = 'hidden' id = 'minute$i' value = ''>
<input type = 'hidden' id = 'second' value = ''>
<br><br>
<span id = 'selectmin$i' value = '0'></span>:<span id = 'selectsec$i' value = '0'></span>
<br><br>";
echo "<script>document.getElementById('selectmin$i').innerHTML = 'Hello '; </script>";
}
?>
```

Also close your while loop with `}` and use `<?php` or `<?` to start your php code.

The output HTML is:

```html
<input type='hidden' id='minute1' value=''>
<input type='hidden' id='second' value=''>
<br>
<br>
<span id='selectmin1' value='0'></span>:<span id='selectsec1' value='0'></span>
<br>
<br>
<script>
  document.getElementById('selectmin1').innerHTML = 'Hello ';
</script>
<input type='hidden' id='minute2' value=''>
<input type='hidden' id='second' value=''>
<br>
<br>
<span id='selectmin2' value='0'></span>:<span id='selectsec2' value='0'></span>
<br>
<br>
<script>
  document.getElementById('selectmin2').innerHTML = 'Hello ';
</script>
<input type='hidden' id='minute3' value=''>
<input type='hidden' id='second' value=''>
<br>
<br>
<span id='selectmin3' value='0'></span>:<span id='selectsec3' value='0'></span>
<br>
<br>
<script>
  document.getElementById('selectmin3').innerHTML = 'Hello ';
</script>
<input type='hidden' id='minute4' value=''>
<input type='hidden' id='second' value=''>
<br>
<br>
<span id='selectmin4' value='0'></span>:<span id='selectsec4' value='0'></span>
<br>
<br>
<script>
  document.getElementById('selectmin4').innerHTML = 'Hello ';
</script>
<input type='hidden' id='minute5' value=''>
<input type='hidden' id='second' value=''>
<br>
<br>
<span id='selectmin5' value='0'></span>:<span id='selectsec5' value='0'></span>
<br>
<br>
<script>
  document.getElementById('selectmin5').innerHTML = 'Hello ';
</script>
```